# Is there a way to redirect all the folders created during build time of a .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Whenever we create a .NET Core project, there are "bin" & "obj" folders which will be created during the build time. Is there a way to redirect "obj" folder. I had used the following in the .csproj,but that didn't help

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>C:\Temp</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApp</AssemblyName>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(OutputPath)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
   <Exec Command="rmdir /S /Q obj" />
 </Target>

 <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
   <Exec Command="rm -r obj" />
 </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Do you only need the `obj` folder

Comment: I don't want any of the folders to be created in the directory where .csproj is located

Comment: Did you try from GUI of VS ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2019

Comment: Tried with command prompt

Comment: No i meant, try setting the output path from VS GUI

Comment: Yes I did try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `BaseOutputPath` (bin) and `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` (obj) properties in the Directory.Build.Props file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019

You can set the `OutputPath` and `IntermediateOuputPath` directly, but this will prevent MSBuild from creating architecture (x64/x86) and configuration (Release/Debug) specific folders, so usually best to leave this in.

It looks like the point at which msbuild consumes these properties in SDK project loading is before the individual csproj files, so to get them to be used, you need to set them in `Directory.Build.Props` next to the solution file.

The file should look like this (plus anything that you already had in it if you have one):

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>C:\TestFolder</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>C:\TestFolder</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Yes i tried BaseOutputPath and BaseIntermediateOutputPath but still "obj" folder gets created in the same directory where the .csproj is located.
Tried outdir but it requires the "obj" to succeed

Comment: Updated after a little research. Turns out that these properties have to be set at a Directory.Build.Props level rather than at the individual project level. They can be made to work on an individual project level, but it's hackier: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2070